# Sorting as a child of ArrayList

Tags: java, sorting, inheritance, arraylist, collections

my professor tasked me with sorting a SoftDrinkList Class that extends to ArrayList of SoftDrinks in both ascending and descending order but I can't seems to get it to work

```
private void sort(boolean isAscending){
    if (isAscending){
        Collections.sort(super(),Collections.reverseOrder((a,b) -> {
        return a.getPrice().compareTo(b.getPrice());
    }));
    }
}
```

I am quite new to Java so I don't really know the inner working of its, any help would be appreciated.
PS: is there any way to create a temporary sorted ArrayList from the current one? As I only need to print in sorted order, I don't really want to sort the actual array. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean you can't get it to work? What is wrong with it?

Comment: Netbeans comment " 'void' type not allowed here " when I hover over the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your function to return a sorted copy of the original list. Assuming you're using a class called `SoftDrink`, you can do:

```
 private ArrayList<SoftDrink> sort(boolean isAscending){
    ArrayList<SoftDrink> copy = new ArrayList<>(originalList); // creates a copy of your original list
    Comparator<SoftDrink> ascendingComparator = new Comparator<SoftDrink>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(SoftDrink a, SoftDrink b) {
            return a.getPrice() - b.getPrice();
        }
    };
    if (isAscending) {
        copy.sort(ascendingComparator);
    } else {
        copy.sort(Collections.reverseOrder(ascendingComparator));
    }

    return copy;
}
```

Comment: what does line 3 to 8 mean if I may ask, and how does it help with the sort?

Comment: Comparator is used for when you want to sort your array based on a custom attribute in your object (i.e. `private int price;`). The `compare(...)` function is used to determine the order of the objects: If the a's price is greater than b, or b's price is greater than a. In the `compare(...)` method, if the result of the subtraction is <= 0, then it is sorted [a,b]. Else, [b, a]

Comment: I see, I have tried your method, but for the originalList part in line 2, I don't know how to refer to the current ArrayList as it is coded like this:
```
public class SoftDrinkList extends ArrayList<SoftDrink>{
  (sort methods here)
}
```

Comment: You can simply refer to it by using `this` keyword. So you would have `ArrayList<SoftDrink> copy = new ArrayList<>(this);`